# How to save to Windows registry the language chosen when setup.exe (from INNO 5.5.4) is executed?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a Build (*.iss) file for INNO that gives the user the possibility of choosing between 4 languages when the setup.exe is executed. I would like the language chosen by the user to be saved in the Windows registry (or in a file where the setup.exe is located). This would be used as input to the installed program. The installed program will then dynamically change the language used for the menu items/messages to the language chosen by the user.

How can I this task be accomplished in the INNO *.iss file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the value given by the [`{language}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#language) constant. It returns the selected language identifier name (the name specified by the [`Name`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_languagessection.htm#Name) parameter of the [`[Languages]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_languagessection.htm) section entry). For instance, the following script will store either `en` or `nl` value (depending on which language the user selects) to the specified registry key:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program

[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "nl"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Dutch.isl"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Language"; ValueData: "{language}"
```

In a code you can query the [`ActiveLanguage`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_languagessection.htm#Name) function, which returns the same language identifier as the [`{language}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#language) constant. To store this identifier into a text file in the form you've mentioned after the installation is done, you can use the following code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program

[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "de"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  S: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    S := Format('language = "%s"', [ActiveLanguage]);
    SaveStringToFile('C:\File.txt', S, False);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply TLama --- I have tested your 2nd suggestion [Code] and this works fine. However, I need to write this to a *.txt file that I can read when I start my application. How can I handle this in my *.iss file?

Comment: You've mentioned registry in your question (that's why I've removed the code part in this post update). Well, how do you want to store that value in text file ? Will that be a true text file, or an INI file with `Key=Value` pairs ? Anyway, update your question accordingly and add all details there, please.

Comment: @user1435385: Your question here asks about writing to the **registry**, which is the question that was answered. Next time, ask the question you really want answered in the first place.

Comment: Sorry about that @user1435385. Back to your question TLama. It will be a true *.txt file (ASCII) and if the language chosen is German, then the following could be written to this file: language = "de".

Comment: Ok, I've added the code sample which saves the string in the format you've mentioned in the post. Note the last boolean parameter of the `SaveStringToFile` function. If it's False, which currently is, it will overwrite the file if already exists. If you change that parameter to True, it will only append that text to an existing file (without a line feed).

Comment: Thanks very much TLama! Including your code in my *.iss file caused the following to be written to the C:\File.txt file: language = "german", which is as it should be. How could I change your code so that this file would be in the same directory as where MyAppExeName = "TestV.exe" is located? In my specific case I am using the following path to my application: C:\Program Files\MyAppName. Note, that MyAppName = "TestV" and I am using the default C:\Program Files as the "base" directory.

Comment: To TLama: I have thought about trying to work with an *.ini file (in reference to your first message); but, have no experience with using this type. What are some of the advantages/disadvantages of using an *.ini file when compared to using a *.txt file?

Comment: You're probably looking for the `{app}` constant which indicates the folder which user can select on one of the wizard pages. All you need to do then is to expand that constant to get the value of it, e.g. writing this `SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\File.txt'), S, False);` will save the `File.txt` into the folder which user could choose on the *"Select Destination Location"* wizard page.

Comment: Advantage of an INI file, which is just a structured text file, is that many programming languages have ready made support for reading values from them. Those files can be then read e.g. by a single call to a function where you specify section and key name and the function returns value of that key from the section. With a pure text file you need to parse the text by yourself.

Comment: Yes TLama --- worked exactly as you stated (jätte bra -- Swedish for very, very good). Thanks very much for your "hand holding" through this session. Best regards and have a good day.